Run a script that checks for SQL Server changes that returns a boolean value
I already plan on doing this differently with webhooks, but for now I just need to show a PoC for this where the browser client will check on intervals if there's any changes to an SQL Server database and return a boolean value if it detects a change, where then my client side script will refresh the page if the bool value is true.
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
        function refreshPage() {
            window.location.href = data.rtnurl;
        }
        setInterval(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'testscript', //script to check data base update
                type: 'GET',
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data === 'true') {
                        refreshPage();
                        alert("New data was added.");
                    }
                }
            });
        }, 30000);
});
</script>

Here's what I have right now, and was wondering how I would be able to use the URL to run a script to check for SQL Server updates.

Take a peek into Server-Sent Events (SSE)

I have this in my bucket list for future implementation, for now I'm just trying to have a script run to check for changes and return a boolean value. Thank you.

If you want to reuse existing http concepts, then you could implement support for a HEAD request with an If-Modified-Since / If-Match header. Any implementation would require server api changes.

Well, if the database has a "row version" column, then that value will change when that row record is updated.
Hence, a simple web method can "sum up" the time stamp column (row version column). Thus, adding of records, deleting of records, or editing of records will produce a different total for the row version column.
While the name in SQL server is "timestamp", the column is a big int, and it that value is incremented each time the row been changed, and has nothing to do with time at all, despite its name.
So, say this GridView and markup:
<asp:HiddenField ID="datacheck" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />

<asp:GridView ID="GVHotels" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    DataKeyNames="ID" CssClass="table table-hover"
    Width="45%">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="HotelName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Active"
            ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
            HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-Width="120px">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chk1" runat="server"
                    Checked='<%# Eval("Active")%>'
                />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

<asp:Button ID="cmdReLoad" runat="server" 
    Text="Reload data"
    OnClick="cmdReLoad_Click"
    ClientIDMode="Static"
    />


<script>

    var mytimer
    $(document).ready(function () {
        mytimer = setInterval(mycheck,1000)
    })


    function mycheck() {
        var checkvalue = $('#datacheck').val()

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "SimpleGrid.aspx/GetChanged",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {},
            success: function (mydata) {

                if (checkvalue != mydata.d) {
                    // refresh grid - data has changed
                    $('#cmdReLoad').click()
                }
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                var errorMessage = xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText
                alert('Error - ' + errorMessage)
            }
        });

    }
</script>

We placed a hidden field, and we set the value to the sum() of the row version value.
And then client side, we test/check that value against a web method we have for that page.
Hence, code behind looks like this:
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadGrid();
    }

    void LoadGrid()
    {
        string strSQL = @"SELECT * FROM tblhotelsA
                        ORDER BY HotelName";

        GVHotels.DataSource = General.MyRst(strSQL);
        GVHotels.DataBind();

        datacheck.Value = GetChanged().ToString();
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public static long GetChanged()
    {
        string strSQL = 
            "select sum(cast(ts as bigint)) as MyChanged from tblhotelsA";
        
        DataTable dtChanged = General.MyRst(strSQL);
        long MyChanged = (long)dtChanged.Rows[0]["MyChanged"];

        return MyChanged;

    }

    protected void cmdReLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadGrid(); 
    }

So, if the data has been changed, then we click a button to re-load the GridView. Of course, once all is working fine, then you can hide that button that the jQuery code clicks with this:
        <asp:Button ID="cmdReLoad" runat="server" 
            Text="Reload data"
            OnClick="cmdReLoad_Click"
            ClientIDMode="Static"
            style="display:none"
            />

So, we check the server every 1 second, and if the data been changed, then we click the button to re-load the GridView.
Edit: Return a true/false value
As noted, returning a true/false value, or returning a value that we check for a change quite much amounts to the same result.
However, assuming you JUST looking for some web method to return true, or false, then that suggests we have to persist the "sum()" value server side, and that also can be done.
So, the server side code then becomes this:
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadGrid();
    }

    void LoadGrid()
    {
        string strSQL = @"SELECT * FROM tblhotelsA
                        ORDER BY HotelName";

        GVHotels.DataSource = General.MyRst(strSQL);
        GVHotels.DataBind();

        GetChanged();
    }

    [WebMethod ]
    public static bool GetChanged()
    {
        string strSQL = 
            "select sum(cast(ts as bigint)) as MyChanged from tblhotelsA";
        
        DataTable dtChanged = General.MyRst(strSQL);
        long MyChanged = (long)dtChanged.Rows[0]["MyChanged"];
        long previous = 0;
        if (HttpContext.Current.Session["checksum"] == null)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session["checksum"] = MyChanged;
            previous = MyChanged;
        }
        else
        {
            previous = (long)HttpContext.Current.Session["checksum"];
        }

        return (MyChanged != previous); 

    }

And client side code is now this:
            function mycheck() {

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "SimpleGrid.aspx/GetChanged",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {},
                    success: function (mydata) {
                        if (mydata.d) {
                            alert('data been changed')
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                        var errorMessage = xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText
                        alert('Error - ' + errorMessage)
                    }
                });

            }

Of course, one more addition is that when you trigger the refresh code (not clear what that routine does), then you need to re-set the session value server side. So, the 2nd example now returns true, or false from the server. Note that the data.d (the ".d") part is how asp.net web forms returns a value, and you have to use ".d" if you are using webforms.

I'm curious why you're using Webforms. OP has indicated they're using ASP.NET, but nothing more specific, and only through a post tag.

Without more information, then it kind of open hunting season then right? And at the end of the day, most of the  concepts shared in this post quite much applies to just about any flavor of asp.net. So, hey, why not post some useful code. The ideas here are not limited to webforms. However, without additional information from the poster, then I can only assume they are happy with any code and any answer as a result. Hence based on provided information the only valid and logical assumption at this point in time is they don't really care if this is webforms or not, and thus are looking for ideas

This is actually pretty useful information, albeit for a future use case, although the row version column idea is extremely helpful for me as I can take that and use it to detect changes. For now I just need a script that will check on the row version column for changes and then return a boolean value. I'm relatively new to this and additional ideas can help wonders.
I apologize for not clarifying things, I have edited the asp.net tag for a much narrower scope.

Well, the real question is then when you have that true/false, what are you planning to do? I have to assume that the THEN part of the question is to re-load the data, or re-fresh the page - that's what the post code does.  So, while we don't return a true/false value, we return a sum() value that can be checked in the client side JavaScript code, and then takes action based on if the data been changed. I suppose I can re-write the code to simply return a true/false value, but the end result of the posted code produces the same result. However, we can have that "test/check" occur server side

All I need for now is to get that sum() value of the rowversion/timestamp, and the client side will just check for any changes on that sum() value, return true/false and then reload the data being displayed.
As with the code I've posted, that's just something I came up with while reading the syntax and I don't even know if it'll work properly for my use case.

Ok, so see my edit and additional ideas. As noted, we can have the server side routine return true, or false, but overall, it is probably better (and easier) using client side code here as per my first example.

Thank you, this helped me a lot and gave me ideas for some future use cases. Sorry for the late response.
